# how to write a formula in Excel that matches multiple figures

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, vlookup

I have the first sheet with Location in column A and item number in Column B.
In the second sheet I have the same data, but also the latest time this item has been used.
I need to write a formula that, if A and B in page 1 are both matching A and B in page 2, then column 8 from page two will be reported in column C in page 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set up an example to answer your question. I have sheet1 and sheet2. Sheet1 I have populated like you stated:

[image]

On Sheet2 I have a copy with a Latest Time column:

[image]

So to retrieve the latest time from Sheet2 to Sheet1 if the A and B column have a match, I put this formula in my C field:

```
=iferror(INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,1 + MIN(IF(Sheet2!A:A=Sheet1!A2,IF(Sheet2!B:B=Sheet1!B2,ROW(Sheet2!A:A),-2),-2))),"")
```

This is placed in Sheet1 C2 and could be dragged down for more.

Let me break this formula down. The IF statement looks for if the range of A:A in sheet 2 matches Sheet1's A2 value AND IF B:B matches Sheet1's B2 value, then it retrieves the row number. I did it this way in case there are multiple instances found, it will only retrieve one value. The INDEX command then simply looks up in Sheet2's C column for the value at the found row.

If the A and B values are not found then a -2 is reported (but added by 1 in the formula. In this case an error would be thrown since a row -1 does not exist so then the IFERROR command kicks back a blank ("")